# How do I add an if / else?

Tags: php, if-statement

I am using the following code to pass a variable. `if variable = a`, do nothing.

I then want to check `if variable = a`, do nothing, `if b`, do nothing, else do something

```
<?
    if($_GET['pageid'] == 'a'){
    } else {
    include('header_image.php');
    }   
?>
```

Above is the code I have working correctly for one vartiable.

How do I add an if / else?

Comment: you're already checking if the get variable is a, why do it twice?

Comment: Because I need to check 2 variables

Answer (score 1):

```
if($_GET['pageid'] != 'a' && $_GET['pageid'] != 'b'){
//do smth
}
```

Comment: This is probably a good approach only branching when the condition is met, not each time you want to "do nothing"

Comment: Thanks for your reply, unfortunately the code above did not work

Answer (score 0):

This is a comment - i want the formatting...

To do what you want:

```
if  ($_GET['pageid'] == 'a') {
    // do nothing for now
} 
elseif ($_GET['pageid'] == 'b') {
   // do some more nothing... 
} 
else { // we do something...
   include('header_image.php');
}
```

You could combine the 'do nothing' tests as:

```
if  (    $_GET['pageid'] == 'a'
      || $_GET['pageid'] == 'b') {
    // do nothing for now
} 
else { // we do something...
   include('header_image.php');
}
```

I agree it reads better than the 'not equal and' tests. However, that is what 'programmers' use so it is worthwhile getting used to it.